# Call Method on createClass result Should be simple

Tags: reactjs

I would like to call a method on a random component after creating it but before rendering it. To perform child specific calculations for the parent prior to rendering the parent. A simple static should work.

```
class Container extends ReactWrapper{

    render() {
    const rClass = React.createClass(this.getCCArgs());
    var newData = rClass.expectedUtilityFunction(data); 
    // render parent with new data.
      return (<div {...this.props.data, ...newData}>
          {rClass}
      </div>);
   };
};
```

Tried a number of ways and the utility method is always not found.
I could push things up the line logically and add a method to return the class used to create the react instance from the input data but I already have the react class instance.

Comment: Can you provide some code? 
I suppose React requires class name starting with capital letter. Just tried and found out `rClass` failes while `RClass` as variable name works fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ctnqkp

Answer (score 0):

`React.createClass` is [deprecated](https://daveceddia.com/convert-createclass-to-function-component/) and removed from React 16+. So I suggest stop tring to make it work.

Your code is good fit for [High order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

Below is sample code (I didn't tested it, so use it as hint only)

```
function WrappedComponent (Component, props) {
    var newData = /* Here is good place for expectedUtilityFunction code. Don't put expectedUtilityFunction function into Component, put it here, in HOC body */ 
    // render parent with new data.
    return (<div {...props.data, ...newData}>
        <Component/>
    </div>);
}
```

And use HOC like this

```
class Container extends ReactWrapper{
    constructor(props) {
        supre(props);
        // Assuming that this.getCCArgs() returns component
        this.hoc = WrappedComponent (this.getCCArgs(), props);
    }

    render() {
        return this.hoc;
    }
}
```